# Having errors with 2D arrays

Tags: arrays, printf, clang

#include<stdio.h>

void createInitialBoard(char board [3][3]){

```
int i;
int j;


for (i=0; i<=3; i++)
{
    printf("\n");

    for (j=0; j<=3; j++)
    {
        printf("? \t", board[i][j]);               //error here 

    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

}

int main(void)
{
char board[3][3];

```
createInitialBoard (board [3][3]);         //error here
```

}

Answer (score 0):

if your array has 3 index "for statement" must be i<3

like that

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    printf("\n");

    for (j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        printf("? \t", board[i][j]);               //error here 

    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: I tried that already and it still gives warnings , not errors. Hope you can help me with that.